# javascript manipulate an object by adding/looping keys and values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am working on a shopping cart function exercise. The function needs to take add one `item` in the `cart`, and it prints out `item name` has been added to your cart, or Your cart is empty if no item has been added.

I also need to create an object to store the item prices generated by Math.Random * 100.

Both the item name and the item price should be stored in an object. The object will be passed on to the next function for user to view the cart.

Here is my attempt, but it keeps turning more than one item at once.

```
function addToCart(item) {
  item = ["pizza", "salt", "apples"]
  var price = []
  var priceRandom = Math.random() * 100
  var priceItem = Math.floor(priceRandom)

  for (var i =0; i<item.length; i++){
  cart.push(item[i])
  console.log(`${item[i]}has been added to your cart. `)
}

  var cartList = {
    item[i], priceItem[i]
  }

  return cartList

}
```

Comment: `Object`'s prototype has interesting methods for this : `Object.keys(obj)`

Therefore, to iterate through keys/properties you can do : 

    `var keys= Object.keys(obj);
    for(var k of keys) {  }`

Answer (score 0):

Im not going to do your whole exercise, neither should I.

But here you have an object ´items` which contains two arrays (name and price)

```
var items = {
    names: ["pizza", "salt", "apples"],
    price: []

}
```

And with a `forEach()` we will loop through all the `names` in the `items` object and give them a price.

```
items.names.forEach(function() {
    var priceRandom = Math.random() * 100
    var priceItem = Math.floor(priceRandom)
    items.price.push(priceItem);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. setting the items as an object does help to restructure the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

```js
function shopingcart(items){
let cart =[];
items.forEach((v,i)=> {cart[i] = {food: v,price: Math.floor(Math.random(i)*100)}});
return cart 
}

var items = ['pizza', 'salt', 'apples']
var cart = shopingcart(items);    

console.log(cart);
// iterate by key value
cart.forEach((item)=>{
console.log( item.price)
console.log(item.food)
})
```